# why angularjs ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying out the basics of AngularJS first time. I am trying out ng-repeat first time. However it is not working.

Here is a non working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mahesha999/XPjNy/1/).

I have written the code in single standalone HTML file as follows and also angular.js file resides in the same directory

```
<html ng-app> 
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var users = [
                      {
                          name:"Mahesh",
                          description:"A geek",
                          age:"22"
                      },
                      {
                          name:"Ganesh",
                          description:"A nerd",
                          age:"25"
                      },
                      {
                          name:"Ramesh",
                          description:"A noob",
                          age:"27"
                      },
                      {
                          name:"Ketan",
                          description:"A psychopath",
                          age:"26"
                      },
                      {
                          name:"Niraj",
                          description:"Intellectual badass",
                          age:"29"
                      }
                    ];
    </script>       
</head> 
<body>
    <div>
        <div data-ng-repeat="user in users">
            <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
            <div>{{user.description}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have not define the controller such as myapp.controller("AppController",function($scope){
 $scope.users=[
                      {
                          name:"Mahesh",
                          description:"A geek"
                      },
                    ];
}); /// than you can call controller to the view such as below code :<body ng-controller="AppController">
    <div><div data-ng-repeat="user in users">
            <h2 ng-bind="user.name"></h2>
            <div>{{user.description}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`users` must refer to a property that is accessible on the current scope. Scopes are AngularJS way of tying data from and to HTML.  This is explained further in the "Model and Controller" chapter of the [second tutorial page](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02). See a working version of your Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9yHjj/).

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

you have not define the controller such as

```
myapp.controller("AppController",function($scope){
 $scope.users=[
                      {
                          name:"Mahesh",
                          description:"A geek"
                      },
                    ];
});
```

/// than you can call controller to the view such as below code :

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">
    <div><div data-ng-repeat="user in users">
            <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
            <div>{{user.description}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Live Example you can access by this link : http://jsfiddle.net/9yHjj/

Answer (score 0):

Your code should have been like this....

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module("app",[]).controller(AppController,["$scope",function($scope){
 $scope.users=[
                      {
                          name:"Mahesh",
                          description:"A geek",
                          age:"22"
                      },
                      {
                          name:"Ganesh",
                          description:"A nerd",
                          age:"25"
                      },
                      {
                          name:"Ramesh",
                          description:"A noob",
                          age:"27"
                      },
                      {
                          name:"Ketan",
                          description:"A psychopath",
                          age:"26"
                      },
                      {
                          name:"Niraj",
                          description:"Intellectual badass",
                          age:"29"
                      }
                    ];
}])
    </script>       
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppController">
    <div>
        <div data-ng-repeat="user in users">
            <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
            <div>{{user.description}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html ng-app="myapp1">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myapp = angular.module("myapp1",[]);
myapp.controller("AppController",function($scope){
 $scope.users=[
                      {
                          name:"Mahesh",
                          description:"A geek",
                          age:"22"
                      },
                      {
                          name:"Ganesh",
                          description:"A nerd",
                          age:"25"
                      },
                      {
                          name:"Ramesh",
                          description:"A noob",
                          age:"27"
                      },
                      {
                          name:"Ketan",
                          description:"A psychopath",
                          age:"26"
                      },
                      {
                          name:"Niraj",
                          description:"Intellectual badass",
                          age:"29"
                      }
                    ];
});
    </script>       
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppController">
    <div>
        <div data-ng-repeat="user in users">
            <h2 ng-bind="user.name"></h2>
            <div>{{user.description}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code should work